# CDNs that host javascript libraries (ie. CodeMirror)

Tags: javascript, cdn

Do you guys know of [CDNs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) that let you load JavaScript libraries from, the way that [Google does with jQuery](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery) and a few others.

I'm looking for one that hosts [CodeMirror library](http://codemirror.net/).

Comment: how about http://codemirror.net/js/codemirror.js ?

Comment: @zengr - Have you seen what you've just posted? *`"My server is not for hotlinking. Download CodeMirror from http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror and put it on your own server. It's not that hard."`*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like no one, but you can vote for Google to take care about it, hopefully they would implement it:

[Add Codemirror to Libraries API](http://code.google.com/p/google-ajax-apis/issues/detail?id=480)

Answer (score 4):

Codemirror is hosted on [cdnjs.com](http://cdnjs.com).